# How to render multiply models in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I have 3 models currency, income and income_operations. I wanna to render them on some route. What is the right way to do it? How can i render three models on one page?

**UPD:** This models don't have any associations between them.

route.js.coffee

```
@route 'addincome', { path: 'operations/addincome' }

EmberMoney.AddincomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    EmberMoney.IncomeOperation.find()
```

templates/addincome.handlebars

```
<div class="row container-bg"><br>
<div class="span6">
  <ul>
      {{#each operation in controller}}
        <li>{{operation.sum}}</li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="span6">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
</div>

// I want to render here more models! For example:

  <ul>
      {{#each income in incomes}}
        <li>{{income.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you want to be rendered?

Comment: how are the 3 models related to each other? ie- hasMany or belongsTo

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but in the route's setupController you could:

```
# excuse the coffeescript...
setupController: (controller) ->
  controller.set('incomes', App.Income.find());
```

then in your template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each income in controller.incomes}}
    <li>{{income.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
```